# Hit Detection on 2D array in Processing

Tags: processing

I'm trying to make a Space Invaders type game using images in a 2D array. I'm trying to create the hit detection needed for the bullet from the defender when hitting one of images in a 2D array. The image does not have one colour going across the front so colour detection can't be used. My idea was to just check the x and y coordinates of the bullet and the array using a nested loop.

```java
boolean isHit(){
   for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
     for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
       if(invArray[j][i].x==x && invArray[j][i].y==y){
         return true;
       }
     }
   }
   return false;
  }
```

Comment: For each invader you can can store a bounding box (x,y,width,height), which you also might use to render the image on screen. A simple test can be checking if a bullet's coordinates are within an invader's bounding box. Not super accurate, but ok for a start

Answer (score 0):

George's comment is exactly correct.

I'll just add that you should get into the habit of [breaking your problem down into smaller steps](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and taking on those steps one at a time.

For example, I would start by creating a separate example sketch that just shows a rectangle. Now make it so that rectangle changes color whenever the mouse is inside it. Get that working perfectly before moving on. Then make it so instead of the mouse position, it's a bouncing circle- change the color of the rectangle whenever the circle is inside the rectangle.

When you have that working perfectly, then move on to a 2D array of rectangles. Get that working perfectly, then it should be pretty easy to switch to images instead of rectangles.

Work in small steps, and work on them in isolation without worrying about the rest of your project. Then if you get stuck, you can post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of just that specific step, and we can go from there. Good luck.